# Garageband Loops in Indie Game Apps?

Tags: ios, garageband, copyright

Are the loops and sound effects that are found in Garageband royalty free?

Specifically, can I use them in my game that I am developing for the iOS App Store whether I sell the App or make it free?

Answer (score 2):

Apple has a [support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2931) describing the license:

> The GarageBand software license agreement says:
>
> "GarageBand Software. You may use the Apple and third party audio loop content (Audio Content), contained in or otherwise included with the Apple Software, on a royalty-free basis, to create your own original music compositions or audio projects. You may broadcast and/or distribute your own music compositions or audio projects that were created using the Audio Content, however, individual audio loops may not be commercially or otherwise distributed on a standalone basis, nor may they be repackaged in whole or in part as audio samples, sound effects or music beds."
>
> So don't worry, you can make commercial music with GarageBand, you just can't distribute the loops as loops.